# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint: Need data to be saved into two databases at the same time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two `Models`, `PurchaseOrders` and `PurchaseOrderMessages` as shown below. I am implementing this in such a way that a user, while creating a purchase order, enters the purchase order details, `PurchaseOrderName` and a `PurchaseOrderMessage`. I am using my `PurchaseOrderVM` for the `View`. On submitting the details, in the `POST` method, like this:

```
_context.Add(purchaseOrdersObj);
_context.Add(purchaseOrdersMessagesObj);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

I am getting the following error: `The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint`. I understand why I am getting that error. It's becuase my `FOREIGN KEY`, `PurchaseOrderId` is not present in the `database` yet, as the data for `PurchaseOrders` has not been saved.

Is there a way in which I can save the `Message` to the `PurchaseOrderMessages` the same time I save details for `PurchaseOrders`? Also, it has to be done in such a way that the user should be able to add more `PurchaseOrderMessages` in the future to the same `PurchaseOrder`, once the `PurchaseOrder` has been created. And, all the `PurchaseOrderMessages` should be saved so that they can all be printed on the screen one after another.

**PurchaseOrders.cs**

```
public class PuchaseOrders
{
    [Key]
    public int PurchaseOrderId { get; set; }

    public string PurchaseOrderName { get; set; }
}
```

**PurchaseOrderMessages.cs**

```
public class PurhcaseOrderMessages
{
    [Key]
    public int UpdateId { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PurchaseOrder")]
    public int PurchaseOrderId { get; set; }
    public virtual PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrder { get; set; }
}
```

**PurchaseOrderVM.cs**

```
public class PurchaseOrderVM
{
    public int PurchaseOrderId { get; set; }
    public string PurchaseOrderName { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow EF to wire this up, so it can handle saving the objects in the right order. Instead of setting an id, set the navigation property:

```
purchaseOrdersMessagesObj.PurchaseOrder = purchaseOrdersObj;
_context.Add(purchaseOrdersMessageObj);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Do I add `purchaseOrdersMessagesObj.PurchaseOrder = purchaseOrdersObj;` before `_context.Add(purchaseOrdersObj);`, or after?

Comment: You don't need that at all. It's implicitly added via it's relationship to a tracked object.

Comment: It worked Chris! Data added to both tables. Thank you.

Comment: Chris, what if I need to retrieve details of a particular `PurchaseOrder` and along with that, all the messages that belong to it? How can I do that? I understand that I should be posting this as a new question, but since all the source code is here, and since you know the background of the requirement, I wanted to ask it here itself. I apologize.

Comment: You need a collection property on your purchase order for the messages. Then, just include the collection when you query.

Comment: Is it advisable to add the same collections property in `ViewModel` for Messages, instead of adding it in the Model?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It's two separate things. Adding the property in your entity is for being able to retrieve the collection via the entity. Without it, you'll have to query the `DbSet` based on something like the purchase order id. Having the property on your view model is kind of a given, since you want access to the messages. However, that can be populated via either path.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by two solutions:

First:

```
public class PuchaseOrders
{
    public PuchaseOrders(){
        Messages = new List();
    }
    [Key]
    public int PurchaseOrderId { get; set; }
    public string PurchaseOrderName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PurhcaseOrderMessages> Messages{ get; set; }
 }

PuchaseOrders purchaseOrdersObj= new PuchaseOrders(){ PurchaseOrderName = "Pla Pla"};
purchaseOrdersObj.Messages.Add(new PurhcaseOrderMessages(){Message = "Pla Pla"});
_context.Add(purchaseOrdersObj);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Second: if you work with SP (stored procedures) in this project a lot you can write SP to take the two objects data and insert them

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Is it because I have declared the `ForeignKey` on `PurchaseOrdersMessages` table and not on `PurchaseOrders` table?

Comment: No ForeignKey in the right place

try adding 

 **public ICollection<PurhcaseOrderMessages> Messages{ get; set; }**

to **PuchaseOrders**

Comment: Do I try now, or do I need to change anything in my `Controller` since I added `ICollection`?